# Optimization routine code sample

Tags: c++, python, c, algorithm, optimization

I am looking for code source for Sequential Quadratic Programming with C, C++, Python, Matlab. Any reference?

Thanks and regards.

-- scipy source is in Fortran. any other references?
regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python's scipy.optimize module has some good stuff for solving quadratic programming problems.

See here for usage information: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/optimize.html

See here for source code: http://sourceforge.net/projects/scipy/files/scipy/